# Excel round by variable decimal places

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding

I have a huge list of values like:

```
0,1686448
216,4577890
0,00000453
0,0045663
```

and need to round them by the last two values not zero like:

```
0,17
216,46
0,0000045
0,0046
```

The first 2 numbers are not the problem by setting ROUND to 2 Decimals. But for the last 2 numbers like 0,00000453 I get 0.

Is there a formula to round anytime for the last two values not zero?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=INT(A1)+ROUND(MOD(A1,1),INT(2-LOG(MOD(A1,1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split into two criteria: if rounded to 2 d.p. = 0 then round to 2 s.f.

```
=LET(n, A1, sf, 2,  x, ROUND(n,2), IF(x=0, ROUND(n,sf-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(n))))), x))
```

Uses the generic round to significant figures formula

```
ROUND(number,digits-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(number)))))
```